# Passing Optional arguments to Java methods

Tags: java, parameter-passing, option-type

Is it OK to pass Optional as a parameter to Java methods?

As for me it's bad because after passing Optional to the method, we create situation when **method should do two things**:

1. **Some logic when object is present**
2. **Another logic that covers case when object is absent**

For example:

```
public class Example {
    private String receiveSomeString(Optional<SomeReceiver> printer) {
        return printer
                .map(SomeReceiver::getA)
                .orElse("B");
    }

}
class SomeReceiver {
    public String getA(){
        return "A";
    };
}
```

As for me it's break Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and method should do two things.

Is it correct?

Comment: *"What do you think about it?"* -> opinion based questions are off-topic.

Comment: It's definitely kinda weird.  `Optional` and streams are recent additions to Java.  Most folks would just pass in a `SomeReciever` directly and check it for `null`.  Also: make sure you always document behavior for `null` arguments.  Throwing NPE is fine as long as the Java doc says "Throws NPE if this argument is null."

Comment: Yes, but passing nullable object and checking inside the method is a bad approach, because as I mention above it create situation when method should do two things.

Comment: Why is it a bad approach?  `Optional` could be `null` here too, yet you don't check for it (nor document the NPE).

Comment: Using `map` and `orElse` splits the logic. And my example above show just simple example